# Sidebar Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

and cant seem to wrap my head around it just yet. I have a side bar nav with contents.  i would like the contents displayed when a parent menu is clicked thus having to hide the other conents. When other parent menu is clicked the others hide.

here is the css

```
 .sidebarContainer {
    position: relative;
    background: #f1f2f3;
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 1%;             
    overflow: hidden;
    border:blue;
    height:auto;
    clear:both;
    border:5px solid yellow;

}
.sidebarheading {
    width:15% auto;
    border:5px solid green;
}
.sidebarContainer .sidebarheading > .sidebarContent {
    position:relative;
    float: right;              
    border:5px solid red;
    right:450px;
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="sidebarContainer">    
<div class="sidebarheading">        
    <h1>Heading1</h1>
        <div class="sidebarContent">
            <p class="content2">Hey Wassup</p>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="sidebarheading">
    <h1>Heading2</h1>
        <div class="sidebarContent">
            <p class="content1">Hey Wassup</p>
         </div>
</div>
```

here is the jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebarheading').click(function () {
        $('.sidebarContent').hide('slow', function () {
            $('.sidebarContent').html($('sidebarContent').html());
            $('.sidebarContent').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    })
})
```

the border is for testing purposes. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebarContent:gt(0)').hide(); // Show the first one by default

    $('.sidebarheading').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.sidebarContent').hide('slow', function () { // On click hide all
           $this.find('.sidebarContent').fadeIn('slow'); //show the content which is inside the clicked heading.
        })
    })
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSsG/)**

Comment: wow that was fast!! Thanks man. I obviously need lots of pratice :(

Comment: @user2512393 You are welcome. You were almost there, just some tweaks!!! Did this helped..

Comment: Ya that helped alot. i will for sure mark it once im allowed to.